# Segmentation error trying to implement flood fill

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, flood-fill

I'm trying to implement flood fill algorithm for 2d array of characters.

The problem is when i try to run it i get a segmentation error. 
I tried multiple things but i cant figure out whats the problem.

I'm trying with this input: http://pastebin.com/raw/puexQfXY

Screenshot of error: https://gyazo.com/b7e738d1d4f09a5d71a020b34a1e3b6c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void floodFill(int width, int height, char grid[width][height], char replacement, char target, int x, int y)
{
    if(x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height)
    {//check if out of array
        return;
    }
    if(grid[x][y] != target)
    {//check if on other than the target
        return;
    }
    grid[x][y] = replacement; //replace
    floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x + 1, y);//right
    floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x, y + 1);//down
    floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x - 1, y);//left
    floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x, y - 1);//up

}

int main()
{
    int width, height;
    scanf("%d", &width);
    scanf("%d", &height);
    char grid[width][height];
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        getchar();//absorb newline
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            grid[x][y] = getchar();
        }
    }

    floodFill(width, height, grid, 'O', '.', 2, 1);
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {//print array
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            putchar(grid[x][y]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your compiler shouldn't even compile that. Hmm, tried it and it compiles with 8 warnings. If you aren't seeing the warnings, try again with `-Wall` for gcc,clang or `/W4` for microsoft.

Comment: Aside: either move `getchar` down a few lines to be inside the loop, or dump that and use `scanf(" %c", &grid[x][y]);` (note the space which consumes leading whitespace).

Comment: and what's the reason behind doing that? no offece I just dont understand why do that because it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake you have is done is while calling the function inside the function itself.
Just take a lokk at parameters and try to match them with the protoype of the function

Your code

```
floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x + 1, y);//right
floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x, y + 1);//down
floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x - 1, y);//left
floodFill(grid, width, height, replacement, target, x, y - 1);//up
```

It should be

```
floodFill( width, height,grid, replacement, target, x + 1, y);//right
floodFill( width, height,grid, replacement, target, x, y + 1);//down
floodFill( width, height,grid, replacement, target, x - 1, y);//left
floodFill( width, height,grid, replacement, target, x, y - 1);//u
```

Comment: TYSM, I was tunneling so much on other things in my program not realizing this obvious mistake. it helps so much when someone else looks at the code